# html5 new tab opens in quirks mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, debugging, quirks-mode, tabbed-browsing

I've tried all the solutions that fixed this issue for others but it has not worked for me. The problem is that any links with target="_blank" open in quirks mode, consequently never rendering the page. The doctype and head are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/styles.css"/> 
        <!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/ie7.css"> <![endif]-->   
    </head>
```

Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Check that you don't have anything before the DOCTYPE. Anything at all, including white space, comments and invisible characters. Anything like this will cause IE to ignore the doctype and drop into quirks mode. Invisible characters can be particularly nasty. If you're using UTF-8, save your files as "UTF-8 Without BOM".

Comment: I already tried removing all indentation and white space with no luck. The file is saved as "UTF-8", I don't see an option for "UTF-8 Without BOM". This only happens on links with target="_blank".

Comment: This can also happen if the HTML is badly malformed. Did you validate the HTML file?

Comment: I found this script which fixed things: http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=42&id=133&artlang=en

Answer (score 0):

Here are some circumstances:

- The document linked to the href does not have a doctype
- The document linked to the href has a transitional doctype
- The document linked to the href is a frameset